# Why does this AJAX request always fail?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm new to both Ajax and Javascript, and I'm having a heck of a time figuring out why this request is always failing:

```
function sellStock(sellData){   
$.ajax({             
    url: '../controller/sell.php',      
    data: sellData,
    success: function(){
        alert("MADE IT");
        //does stuff                            
    }                               
});
}
```

The only data I can get back about the failed request is "error."  What's the best way to get more info about the problem?

I'm especially confused because this almost-identical function works perfectly on a php file from the same directory:

```
function autoUpdate(s){
$.ajax({ 
    url: '../controller/quote.php',
    data: {symbol: s}, 
    success: function(data){
        //does stuff             
    }                       
});
}
```

There are slight differences between the calls (i.e. autoUpdate() is called from setInterval() while sellStock() is called in a loop by another JS function) but I can't see that any would be a problem.  I'm confident that sellData is in the right form. I've accessed each member that should be there, and, just in case, I've tried it with an anonymous object with the same result.

Can anyone lend me a hand?

Comment: What is saleData? add an error handler.

Comment: I bet `sell.php` is returning a string of "error". Its your php failing, not your ajax request

Comment: The "error" string came from something like this: 

error: function(xml, textStatus){ alert(textStatus); }

The php worked fine before I tried to refactor with ajax

Comment: is there an error in your javascript error log? if not, then it's almost definitely not your ajax request failing. it's probably your php. you should always look at the error log first when something isn't working right.

Comment: Where can I find the error log?

@epascarello: sellData is an object that looks like this:

{
     stock: s,
     shares: stocks[s].shares - currentShares,
     price: Number($('#'+s+'price').html())
    };

Comment: Is the path to `sell.php` correct? And what is `sell.php` returning? Use Firebug (or an equivalent) to help troubleshoot.

Comment: post the contents of `sell.php`..use a pastie if it is too long

Comment: If the PHP worked fine before you started to use ajax, then the data you are passing to PHP isn't working or it is being read in PHP differently than it was before. I would start by commenting out all of the PHP and do a simple `echo $_POST['price'];` for example

Comment: Just like success, add error: `error :  function() { console.log(arguments); }`

Comment: @chris your javascript error log is somewhere in your browser's menu. on mine, it's tools > web developer > error console. once you find it, i recommend just leaving it open all the time while you develop. if you've never used it before you'll be surprised how helpful it is.

Comment: I tried commenting out all of sell.php and replacing it with echo json_encode($_GET);  It still doesn't reach the alert in success, which makes me think there's still some trouble with the Ajax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Download fiddler and run a trace, if you're using IE9+, hit F12, and push the "Start Capturing" button, under the Network tab.
2. If you see a request there, great, dbl click to see the details and may be you'll find your error message there.
3. Alternatively look up [jQuery Error handler](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) in the ajax call, the parameters will get you more detail on your request.
4. If none of the above works, go back to fiddler, click on the `composer` tab try to hand-serialize the payload `sellData` and keep debugging.

Something above should give you a clue to what went wrong.

Comment: Thanks, I'm checking out the fiddler now.  It seems like the ajax call is going to portfolio.php, which is the page it is coming from.

AH! got it. I missed the return in the onsubmit part of the form that calls the function, so the form was submitting and redirecting before the Ajax could happen.  Thanks for all your help guys :)